# React-Native-Maps Error (Super expression must either be null or a function)

Tags: react-native, super, react-native-maps

Can anyone help me with this error?

I learn and copy the code from a YouTube tutorial about React-Native-Maps for displaying current location. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqLC0kOqrwk

The error is: **Super expression must either be null or a function**

I am using latest version of React-Native-Maps
React-Native-Maps Version :"^0.22.1",

[image: This is my code.]
This is my code.

```
      import React from 'react';
      import {
        AppRegistry,
        Component,
        StyleSheet,
        View,
        Text,
        screen,
        Dimensions,
        TouchableOpacity,
        Platform,
      } from 'react-native';

      import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
      import Strings from '../utils/Strings';

      var styles = require('../../assets/files/Styles');
      const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
     const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
     const SCREEN_WIDTH = width
     const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height

    const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.00922;
    const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

      export default class Track extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            title: `${Strings.ST6}`,
          };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

          this.state = {
              initialPosition: {
                  latitude: 0,
                  longitude: 0,
                  latitudeDelta: 0,
                  longitudeDelta: 0
              },
              markerPosition: {
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
              }
            }
        }

        watchID = null

        componentDidMount(){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
                var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

                var initialRegion = {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: long,
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGTITUDE_DELTA
                }

                this.getState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
                this.getState({markerPosition: initialRegion})
            },
            (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
            {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000})

            this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
                var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
                var long = parseFloat(position,coords,longitude)

                var lastRegion = {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: long,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGTITUDE_DELTA,
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA
                }

                this.setState({initialPosition: lastRegion})
                this.setState({markerPosition: lastRegion})
            }) 
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <View style={style.container}>
                <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                region={this.state.initialPosition}>

                <MapView.Marker>
                    coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}
                    <View Style={styles.radius}>
                        <View Style={styles.marker}>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </MapView.Marker>
                </MapView>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

I guess the error is somewhere around

> ```
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props)
> ```
>
> But I don't see a error here, the super should be fine, the result is same even I remove the (props).

Comment: That code is syntactically valid. I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @JaredSmith :( Thank you Jared

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that something is overwriting the definition of Component and you're trying to extend something with your class definition that isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

On your code `class Track extends Component` you forget to call the **react** properties. please change your code to be `class Track extends React.Component`.

Because you just call the Component, and react doesn't know where 'Component' comes from